# Which /Library/Preferences/*.plist does what? Clearing systems remembered monitor positions

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors

I'm sitting on a multi-monitor setup (3 extras). I have to connect them in a very unintuitive order, for my system to 'remember' the position correctly. If I don't do that - or connect the monitors too quickly after one another, then I have to go to System Settings and rearrange them. It's terrible, for days where I have many meetings.

I would like to delete all the settings according to my monitor locations, so when I attach them again, there is no remembered setup.

I Googled around and can see that there is a file: `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist`

But I can't figure out what that file contains. I can't read the contents. And I can't find it online.

---

How do I figure out what these `.plist`-files contains?
And can I safely delete/rename this one - or will my computer explode?

Comment: That one defines boot defaults. There's another in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.[UUID].plist` Deleting the user one should regenerate next boot… meaning you'll have to set it up by hand again. Deleting the main one, it's said it *should* regenerate, but google says many times it doesn't. I don't know what the effect of this would be - but you shouldn't get locked out by it. I really don't think it's going to fix your issue. I just checked mine & it's shown as being created at last boot 29 days ago, without me ever deleting it]

Comment: OK…I tried this, just for *"fun"* as I always have a similar affinity issue. Of two monitors, my Mac always determines the 'wrong' one to be Primary. It will change if I force it, but the startup logo forever remains on the 'wrong' one. I have always considered this is actually a preference of the GPU not the Mac itself. After trashing all the plists & reset SMC, it started still with its preferred primary, then set them up backwards, but with all my windows on the 'wrong' screen. Resetting the display arrangement & rebooting still left me having to move every window by hand. Not recommended.